# how to plot sum of symbols in the specific period with a line?

Tags: plot, pine-script, tradingview-api

[Tradingview pine script]

'BTC.D'+'ETH.D' =

```
    plot(request.security('BTC.D','D')+request.security('ETH.D','D'),color.white)
```

> Value of 'BTC.D' start from Apr, 2014
> // Value of 'ETH.D' start from Jul, 2017.

This code make a line with value of  'BTC.D'+'ETH.D' by daily.

problem:

If i use 'BTC.D'+'ETH.D', i can't find a value of BTC.D in Apr,2014~Jun,2017 too.

I think the problem is because a value of ETH.D is uncallable in Apr,2014~Jun,2017.

how to make uncallable data to 0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `nz()` function which will replace NaN values with zeros.

```
btc = nz(request.security('BTC.D','D', close))
eth = nz(request.security('ETH.D','D', close))
plot(btc, color=color.green)
plot(eth, color=color.red)
```

Comment: It works well. i finally make crypto dominance(Large, Mid, Small) owing to u.